# High-side driver IC use of diode in the npn transistor BE

Tags: diodes, integrated-circuit, power-electronics, mosfet-driver, bootstrap

I would like to know why is used a diode between the BE of the npn in this circuit. The npn is used to boost the current to deliver to M2 gate in this bootstrap circuit.
Is it maybe needed to get rid of the accumulated charge during ON operation of the npn itself? (conductivity modulation)
[image]

Here another high-side and the diodes are still present

[image]

Comment: For the first picture: When the M1 is in saturation region (square wave high), the diodes and the BJT's BE junction create a fairly constant voltage drop. So \$V_{R} = V_{aux} - V_{D1} - V_{extradiode} - V_{BE} - V_{M1VDS}\$, where \$V_{M1VDS}\$ is very small. When M1 is off (square wave low), the \$V_{R} = V_{D1} = V_{extra_diode} = V_{BE} = 0V\$, while \$V_{M1VDS} = V_{aux}\$.

Comment: If the diode wasn't there how would you turn the gate off?

Comment: Can you give the original source of your [top picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ6bV.jpg), and so answer this [new question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/338296/help-me-find-a-book-with-this-bootstrap-circuit-pictures-below) which asks about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the diode (= no connection), what would be the path to discharge M2's gate??

And without the diode (= shorted) there would be no role for the NPN transistor.

Answer (score 2):

Call the bipolar NPN Q1 and the base emitter diode D1.

The diode replaces the lower transistor in what would otherwise be a 2 transistor driver. It provides a pull down path using the previous driver stage.

Usually the gate of M2 would be driven by a 2 transistor driver which was able to pull its gate high to turn it on and to pull its gate low to turn it off.
The designer has decided that M1 has enough drive capability to be able to be used to pull M2's gate low. M1-drain is connected to M2-gate by D1. When M1 is on it pulls M2-gate low via D1 and turns M2 off.
To turn M2 on the deigner COULD have used just R to provide pullup drive to M2-gate. However, R cannot supply enough current to provide the gate charge required by M2 in an acceptably short time. So Q1 is provided as an emitter follower to pull M2-gate high when required.

In this manner M2 is provided with bipolar drive - high via Q1 and low via D1 + M1.

Note that this answer is another way of saying what Wouter's answer says.